# >Does the inequality hold: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(\log \log 2)^n}{n!}>\dfrac{3}{5}$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

> Does the inequality hold:

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(\log \log 2)^n}{n!}>\dfrac{3}{5}$

**My attempt**:

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(\log \log 2)^n}{n!}=e^{\log (\log 2)}=\log 2=0.301$.

$\dfrac{3}{5}=0.6$. So the inequality does not hold.

But the answer says it is true.Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: $\ln(2)$, not $\log(2)$?

Comment: in mathematics, if it says $\log$ with no notation, it means base $e \approx 2.71828.$

Comment: ln(2)=0.6931>0.6

Comment: Why will it be $\ln 2$ @MichaelBurr; Please show the calculations

Comment: Does not $\log$ mean base $10$

Comment: There's some serious notational confusion here.  I think that the problem means $\ln$ when it writes $\log$.  However, if you wanted to use $\log$ as a base $10$ logarithm, then $e^{\log(\log 2)}\not=\log 2$ because the bases aren't right.  So, as soon as you use $e^{\log(\log(2))}=\log 2$, you are *automatically* using the natural logarithm for $\log$.

Comment: Grownups use $\log$ to mean the natural logarithm, Ben.